# Counting number of pixels using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, pixel, count

There is a raster data which contains specific areas separated by layers. My purpose is to count the number of the pixels in those areas.

Is it possible to do it in the ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1 with a Spatial Analyst license?

Comment: Do you have Spatial Analyst license? In that case you can try Zonal Statistics as Table (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact version of ArcGIS in use, and which extensions you have available.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm):

> Summarizes the values of a raster within the zones of another dataset
> and reports the results to a table.

I belive one of the outputs will be pixel Count (per zone).